# Why is my SQL statement not returning results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, mariadb

The desired statement is:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`='aaa@aaa.com'
```

...which returns a single cell as results.

My PDO prepared statement doesn't return anything. What am I missing?

```
$email = "aaa@aaa.com";

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`=':email;'");
$statement->execute(['email' => $email]);               
$user = $statement->fetch();
echo $user;
```

Comment: Don't add quotes with prepared statements.  `WHERE \`email\` = :email;`

Comment: Also remove the ; from :email; it should be :email without the ; in your query

Comment: @Bolli you are right.

Comment: Shouldn't it also be `execute([':email' => $email])` (with the `:`) in the execute statement? (even though it was the prepare he had issues with right now).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes you are right

Comment: @MagnusEriksson It works either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$email = "aaa@aaa.com";

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`=:email");
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (!empty($row)) {
    print_r($row);
}else{
    echo 'no result :/';
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, this returned "no result", so there might be some issue with my connection or something cause I do get results when I do it in mysqlworkbench.

Comment: I just realized there was a problem with my database selection, I get results now!

Comment: Perfect! I was just about to ask you about that :)

Answer (score 1):

Quote should not be used in :email

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`=:email");
```

as said by @siyual

Answer (score -1):

use it like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE `email`=:email;"); 

$statement->execute(['email' => $email]);
```

also, make sure that

```
$db->prepare('select 1');
```

returns a valid query result.

Comment: I don't understand how the second portion has any relation to the question.

Comment: $test=$db->prepare('select 1');
$test1 = $test->fetch();
echo $test1;

Comment: This doesn't return anything

Comment: @Heraclitus - You need to execute the statement, as well

Comment: My bad I forgot, thanks @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @Siyual second portion will ensure that there are no connection issues to the database. if you get a result with 1 as value ensures that there is no problem with the database connection.